# Login to remote host via scp using expect script

Tags: shell, automation, expect, scp

I want to send a file to many machine by using SCP plus EXPECT to do automatic password prompt for each connection.

I have 3 components which are (1) text file contains username, password, IP, and path; (2) text reader read information from text file and pass these value to SCP file; (3) SCP file.

It should work properly with these components but when I execute, the password prompt still show up. I already tried with manual the value config in SCP file and it work, but not for value passing.

the text file contains multiple line text like

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,user,password,/path/to/directory
```

The text reader script is

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while read line
do
        IPADDR=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $1}');

        US=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $2}');

        PW=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $3}');

        dir_path=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $4}');

        ./scp.sh "${IPADDR}" "${US}" "${PW}" "${dir_path}"
done
```

and the SCP file is

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_user 1
exp_internal 0
set timeout 30
set HOST [lindex $argv 0]
set US [lindex $argv 1]
set PW [lindex $argv 2]
set DIR [lindex $argv 3]
#connect via scp
spawn scp -r "${US}@{HOST}:/home/test/send_file" ${DIR}/moved_file
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "${PW}\r"
}
}
interact
```

I don't know what is the missing point on these components.

Comment: can u try enable the debug and see ? Whether the script is sending the 'yes' to the scp ?

Comment: try `expect -xvf` at the top and see if you get a debug/trace output. Then you should see all the variables that are passed in, and their execution. Also, did you `chmod 755 ./scp.sh`. Scripts need to be marked as executable so the shell will know it is OK to run them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think scp has code especially made to stop people doing this sort of thing.

Passwords are for humans. The equivalents for computers are "ssh keys"

You can create an ssh key (suitable for scp) with ssh-keygen, and use it via `scp -i <ssh-key-file>`.

You will need to add the public key on the server, in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - you can also control in this file exactly what commands are allowed to be run for any given key, improving security further.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys - although this is page is for ArchLinux, it works on other Linuxes too.